# magento product description image missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hello everyone, 
              I need to display a product on magento homepage.That I have done successfully,but when I try to get the product description like this:

load(49); ?>    
getDescription(); ?>

I can get all the product description text but there is an image in product description that I inserted in the through wysiwyg editor that does not appears on the home page.

the link to the image comes to be broken like this(firebug):

The same products description image is displayed well on the product view page.Below is the image code from the product view page(firebug):

bottom line is that while using  getDescription(); ?> I can get the text in the product description but not the image inside product description on home page.

I have searched on it but could not get an exact solution.As the are many post explaining how can we get a products description but non of them explains how to get product description image.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Thank you 
Sarvesh

Answer (score 0):

When you use a WYSIWYG editor in Magento, images are added through directives. If you check the bare description that is being returned by `$product->getDescription()` you will notice a `{media}` directive in there.

If you manually retrieve a description from a product, or any other WYSIWYG data, you need to let a processor filter your content to parse all directives to, in this instance, images.

The `Mage_Cms_Helper_Data` class contains a `getBlockTemplateProcessor()` method. If you let that method parse your content like below, the image should appear.

```
$processor = Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
$content = $processor->filter($content);
```

If you want to learn more about directives. I suggest to checkout the following classes `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter` and `Varien_Filter_Template`.